# EJS and Javascript can't access DOM - Server crash or Document NOT Defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ejs

I'm a begginer in coding. I spend hours to figure out but can't find a solution yet. How to use the DOM with jquery and target the size attribut of an input ?

Since the DOM is not working, I can't manipulate other html elements either.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

**For your information the following dependencies**

"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.20.2",
"ejs": "^3.1.8",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"jquery": "^3.6.4",
"jsdom": "^21.1.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21"
}

Here is the code:

**File: index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);

$('h2').css('color', 'red');

let inputMail = 40;

let colorIs = $('h2').css('color');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
 
    res.render('home', {
        inputMail: inputMail
    });
});

app.get('/blogs/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render();
})
```

**EJS file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://emoji-css.afeld.me/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Learning to code</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

    
        <div class="home_outter">
            <div class="home-top-header">
                <form action="post">
                    <i class='bx bx-envelope'></i>
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Gert tips and actionable insights on how to build amazing projects" size="<%= inputMail %>">
                    <button type="submit">Oui, avec plaisir </button>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="links-external">
                <span class="text" id="externalLink">Coming Soon!</span>
                <i class='bx bxl-instagram-alt'></i>
                <i class='bx bxl-linkedin-square'></i>
                <i class='bx bxl-twitter'></i>

            </div>

        </div>

        <section id="navbar">

            <h2 class="textLogo" id="textLogo" >Learn Code</h2>

           
    </div>

    <div class="footer-padding">
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Made with  by a daydreamer</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

I try to use HTML DOM and Jquery.

Comment: EJS doesn't exist client side, it your server-side templating language that you use to turn a request from the browser into a server response. By the time that response gets set back, there is no "EJS" anymore, only real HTML/CSS/JS/etc. Things like jQuery don't run on your server, they run in your user's browsers, on their computer, because you sent them a normal webpage that loads JS using a `<script>` tag that points to a normal `.js` script URL. What you've done is  you made your HTML try to load a server-side script. That `index.js` is not browser JS.

Comment: In this case, just hit up your favourite search engine, and search for "writing a webpage with express and EJS" and then just follow one of the hundreds of tutorials you find.